# Webrtc RTCdatachannel server c++

Tags: javascript, c++, udp, webrtc

I'm trying to create a simple webrtc server in c++ , so i can transfer data between browser and server (no need for peer-to-peer) and i only need RTCdatachannel no media or audio is involved.
i tried this example:
https://github.com/llamerada-jp/webrtc-cpp-sample

But unfortunately i didn't manage to compile this and also thats an old project so it may be irrelevant now.

Can someone provide a good example ? even some guidelines will be great:)

Answer (score 3):

I recently wrote a standalone library implementing WebRTC Data Channels in C++: https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel

It's way easier to compile than the reference WebRTC full implementation, so since you don't need video or audio, you could use in on the server side. You can find usage examples in the test directory. Note you'll still need to transmit the SDP offer and answer between the client and the server to negociate the data channel.